# String manipulations for javax.xml.transform.Source

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am using Java and XSL style sheets to retrieve values from an XML file and outputting it to a text file.

Below is the program used:

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xsl"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    Source text = new StreamSource(new File("inputXML.txt"));        
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.txt"))) ;
```

But recently I found that the XML files I will be reading will have 2 root nodes and not one.  So I am thinking of doing string manipulation to add a root node of my own programatically so that I can avoid the below error:

> *ERROR:  'The markup in the document following the root element must
>   be well-formed.' ERROR: 
>   'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The
>   markup in the document following the root element must be
>   well-formed.'*

But I am unable to do any String manipulation's on javax.xml.transform.Source (Casting is not working).
I do not want to use intermediate files to add my root node as I fear it will prove costly as i need to be processing close to 50k XML records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [StreamSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) has several constructors

```
Path inputPath = Paths.get("inputXML.txt");
String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(inputPath,
                   StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
input = input.replaceFirst("<quasiroot", "<root>$0")
    + "</root>";

Source text = new StreamSource(new StringReader(input));
```

---

### Update: the newer `Files#readString` (since Java 11):

```
String input = Files.readAllString(inputPath);
```

Comment: I used a slight variation of how "input" is processed to achieve the result . Thank you . much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the Java world you have XML parsers like Xerces with support for [external entities](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-external-ent) so you can simply construct a file referencing your other file e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ENTITY input SYSTEM "inputXML.txt">
]>
<root>&input;</root>
```

then all you need to do is load that file as the source for your XSLT. There is no need for string manipulation, at least not to manipulate the whole XML, if you want, you can construct the above directly as a string and pass it to a StreamSource over a StringReader where you set the system id to the directory of your input XML:

```
    String input = "inputXML.txt";
    File dir = new File(".");
    String baseUri = dir.toURI().toASCIIString();
    String inputXml = "<!DOCTYPE root [  <!ENTITY input SYSTEM \"" + input + "\">]><root>&input;</root>";
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xsl"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    Source text = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXml), baseUri);
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.txt")));
```